# Surrounding DIV background-color and inline-block

Tags: background, css

If I set the background color for a div containing divs which have display:inline-block set, the background color is not used.

JSFiddle links below.

Consider this snippets:

CSS:

```
.divisionOutputArea {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.divisionColumn[data-division=true][data-boxed=true] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.divisionColumn[data-division=true] {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.divisionColumn[data-result=true] {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<div class="divisionOutputArea">
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-division="true" data-boxed="true">
        1<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-division="true" data-boxed="true">
        2<br />2<br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-division="true" data-boxed="true">
        3<br />3<br />3<br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-division="true" data-boxed="true">
        1<br /><br />1<br />1<br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-division="true" data-boxed="true">
        2<br /><br /><br />2<br />2<br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-result="true">
        :<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-result="true">
        5<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-result="true">
        =<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-result="true">
        2<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-result="true">
        4<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-result="true">
        6<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="divisionColumn" data-result="true">
        2<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to render the background of the used area of `<div class="divisionOutputArea">[Contained divs as of example]</div>` e.g. yellow.

Tried it on FF11 and Webkit. Cross-browser is not of an issue.

Not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/8BVZB/

Somewhat working, but not what I want:
http://jsfiddle.net/d6bM6/

Answer (score 1):

The inner divs are float, so you need the clear the float.

A very easy way is to give overflow: hidden to the wrapping element. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/8BVZB/1/)

```
.divisionOutputArea {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, a safe way is to give

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

at the end of wrapping element

Comment: The first overflow: hidden; already sufficed to achieve what I want at least on FF11 and latest webkits).

Answer (score 0):

If you simply remove the `float:left` from the inner divs (and the whitespace between them), you get http://jsfiddle.net/d6bM6/2/
But if that isn't what you want either, you should create a screenshot of how you want it to look.

Comment: Thank you, the blank bite me, that's exactly the output I want.Now which answer to mark as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are correct.

The answer by @Starx has the advantage, that the original CSS need not be touched and the float: left helps to retain HTML source code formatting, which get's blank-sensitive by using display: inline-block.

However, the float: left in the original question was superfluous, as the OP was unaware of blank-sensitivity of display: inline-block, so the answer of @"Mr Lister" is correct as well.

In this special case, the more general answer #1 is not necessary, as the float: left is superfluous.